# How to translate "你给我滚" properly?

Tags: translation

In a sentence like:

“你**给我**拿一杯水” You would translate it something like: ***Get me*** a glass of water.

How is the "给我" in the sentence “你给我滚” supposed to be translated?

Should it just be "Get lost / Piss off" and just ignore the "给我" part?

Comment: ** don't work for Chinese words unless you put spaces around them. See this question on meta. http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/11/bold-tag-not-applied-to-chinese-words-correctly

Comment: I corrected it and also something else...

Comment: Ignore 给我 is good, just keep the same mood

Comment: Maybe "take a hike" means the same thing? I'm not sure how strong that phrase is, though.

Comment: 给我=for my sake.

Comment: should be 拿一杯水?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding to Ciaocibai's answer:

"你给我滚" could be same to "给我滚" and then further reduced to "滚".

In both "你给我滚" and "给我滚", personally, I think the "给我" part is used to make emphasis on strong emotions, such as contempt or strong anger. It will therefore depends on the tune/context to translate it.

E.g. "给我滚一边去", can be used by a gangster head to someone else who is not important, to show his/her contempt and therefore show his/her superiority in the gang.

Or when a father is really angry at his son who commit a crime, he is furious and shouts out loud "给我滚!"

Answer (score 7):

On grammar, “你给我 [doing something]” means: I am ordering you [doing something].

> 你给我做点儿什么！ --- Do something useful for me!
>
> 你给我说清楚！ --- Let me get this straight! Now!
>
> 你给我老实交代！ --- Tell me the truth!
>
> 你给我看清楚一点儿！ --- Watch carefully!
>
> 你给我去死吧！ ---  Go to hell!

That's *natural* Chinese:)

Comment: Very much agreed. An alternative explicit translation could be "said me". 你给我滚 = "You get away, said me."

Answer (score 3):

Too many options, other possible candidates are:

- F**k off!
- Scram!

给我 used in such context is really just for emphasis and not required to be explicitly translated, just note the essence of it.

Answer (score 3):

I see the 给我 as essentially having the same meaning in both sentences, a meaning which could be summarised as 'for me' . That is, the literal meaning of the sentence is 'Fuck off for me!', or 'I want you to fuck off!'. But this is not being polite, not at all. When you shout at someone in English, 'I want you out of here!', adding 'I want you...' isn't an attempt to be nice; it's a strong expression of the speaker's will.

In translation the 给我 can be safely ignored.

Comment: I agree. I think "给" can be glossed as something like "为 (wèi)" in this sentence if the OP is still unclear about this (common) usage.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it is like 'you get away from me', with the 给我 part just meaning get away. I suppose if you were being polite you could translate it as 'give me some space', but to be honest I think it's pretty subjective.

Comment: I don't think this sentence is polite to begin with...

Comment: To whoever downvoted, if you could leave a comment why, that would be great :-)

Comment: "给我" does not mean "get away", that's the "滚" part. And "你给我滚" is never polite.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe get out of my face is a proper translation.

Answer (score 1):

A LITERAL translation would be something like: "Give me space!" But its real (impolite) connotation is more like "get lost" or "buzz off."

Answer (score 1):

你给我滚

Nǐ gěi wǒ gǔn

You for the benefit of me, get lost !

Answer (score 0):

Not to disagree with the excellent responses given so far, but it is important to point out that the word "滚" is a rather blunt, rude word, quite different from “走开” or “去”. One would only say “你给我滚” when extremely angry and isn't concerned about burning bridges. In fact, I'd go so far as to say the equivalent of “你给我滚” in English is "F*** off!" Of course, one may say it jokingly to a friend, but, if you have just learned this expression, it wouldn't be a good idea to use it too soon,

Answer (score 0):

> 你 = you
>
> 给 = pronoun, to introduce the following object
>
> 我 = object, litterally "me"
>
> 滚 = f*ck off

In this case, 给我 does nothing but to emphasize the speaker's will (order, insult). In this sense, it's **unnecessary** to translate them. Normally such usage of 给我 should be appeared in an imperative sentence.

§ Notice that 给我 also means "give sth to me", so the following usage should be avoided.

> 你把水给我 = give (the bottle of) water to me
>
> 你（给我）把水给我 = recurrence of 给我 makes the sentence incomprehensible

If you want to express the same meaning, you should avoid using 给我 to emphasize your mood or replace the verb for the expression of "give"

> 你把水给我！= give (the bottle of) water to me !

You use your tone to express the imperative sentence

or

> 你给我把水**拿**来 = give (the bottle of) water for me

拿 means fetch, not exactly same as 给 which means give, compromism happens while you have to use 给我 to order someone :) Therefore, in the translation here above I would stick to the usage of "give".

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it would mean Go away! Also, 给我 can be safely removed. However, you can also just say 滚！ because it can sometimes function like an interjection.

Answer (score 0):

给我 : meaning: for me
给我滚一边去： get out of here right away for me(not -> i'm ording you that...)

Answer (score -1):

I think `给我` has a meaning of 'order' and 'command'. For example:

`你们给我听好了...` is usually used when a commander is giving orders to his soldiers (and they would never disobey or even doubt the content)

Comment: I don't think that's right. The expression has more of a connotation of "Leave me alone," rather than "do something I say."

Comment: As a native speaker, I use `给我` quite carefully. I don't think it's polite to say it to someone who is not a close friend. At least in this case.